# Get data from two collection with specific data Mongo

Tags: sql, node.js, mongodb, nodes

Get data from two collection from first collection(test1) all data and from second collection (test2) customer name using createdBy and updatedBy from test1 collection.

In createdBy and updatedBy I want fullname from test2 collection:

**Test1 collection:**

```json
{
  "_id": "kcXtyaB7jGPw9Ks",
  "dateCreated": "2022-07-12T13:09:16.270Z",
  "dateModified": "2022-07-12T13:09:16.270Z",
  "data1": 1,
  "data2": 100,
  "data3": 5,
  "createdBy": "xQQrzRgi8",
  "updatedBy": "56sgAeKfx"
}
```

**Test2 collection:**

```json
{
  "_id": "xQQrzRgi8",
  "fullName": "test name created"
},
{
  "_id": "56sgAeKfx",
  "fullName": "test name update"
}
```

**Response be like:**

```
{
 "_id": "kcXtyaB7jGPw9Ks",
  "dateCreated": "2022-07-12T13:09:16.270Z",
  "dateModified": "2022-07-12T13:09:16.270Z",
  "data1": 1,
  "data2": 100,
  "data3": 5,
  "createdBy": "test name created",
  "updatedBy": "test name update"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you can use [$lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) like this:

This query do a "join" between "Test1" and "Test2" using `updatedBy` and `_id` fields.

And after that get the first element in the result (I assume there were only one element because you are comparing with `_id` but if there is more than one you can use another way like `$unwind`) to output the value.

Edit: To get both values (created and updated) you can do a second `$lookup`.

Now the query:

- Get the `updatedBy` name from field `_id` in `Test2`.
- Set value into field `updatedBy`.
- Get the `createdBy` name from field `_id` in `Test2`.
- Set value into field `createdBy`.
- Use `$project` to not output `result`.

```
db.Test1.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Test2",
      "localField": "updatedBy",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "result"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "updatedBy": {
        "$first": "$result.fullName"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Test2",
      "localField": "createdBy",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "result"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "createdBy": {
        "$first": "$result.fullName"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "result": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iJZJV0ydoph)

Comment: you got it correct but I want name in updatedBy and CreatedBy filed both, Like I have two record in test2 collection that both have Id in test1 collection.

Comment: Added response I want. please see updated res in question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my query with below mongo query:

```
db.Test1.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Test2",
      localField: "updatedBy",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "updatedByName",
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Test2",
      localField: "createdBy",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "createdByName",
    },
  },
  {
    $set: {
      updatedBy: {
        $first: "$updatedByName.fullName",
      },
      
    },
  },
  {
    $set: {
      createdBy: {
        $first: "$createdByName.fullName",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      updatedByName: 0,
      createdByName: 0,   
    }, 
  }
])
```

Here is Solved query https://mongoplayground.net/p/7Ekh-q8tkTy